# How would I do a detailed walk-through of a factorial?

Tags: python, recursion, stack, factorial

```
def factorial(x):

    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * factorial(x - 1)

print(factorial(3))
```

How would I do a detailed walk-through with information on the stack at every call and show the data at every return?

I know I have to draw 3 boxes to show what happens at every call, and the data at every return; I just don't know how the function actually works, and how to implement it. This does not require any coding, but an explanation?

***** Update ****
So something like this?

```html
N = 3
4 * factorial (3): 24


N = 2
5 * factorial (4): 120


// and so on....
```

Comment: Try stepping through with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add some `print` lines to know what's happening inside a function call. Such as the following:

```
def factorial(x):
    print("factorial({}) is called".format(x))
    if x == 0:
        print("Reached base branch")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Reached recursive branch")
        result = x * factorial(x - 1)
        print("Exitted recursive branch")
        return result

print(factorial(3))
```

This should let you see how the call to `factorial(3)` eventually calls `factorial(2)`, `factorial(1)`, and `factorial(0)` and then goes up the recursive hierarchy when the based case is reached.

Comment: So something like this maybe: ``` N = 5
2 * factorial (1): 2 ``` then ``` N = 4
3 * factorial (2): 6 ``` and so on?

Comment: take a look at my answer above, it is formatted better

Comment: Yes, you can surely do that. The general idea is just to add `print` lines at different places in the function body so you know the values of the arguments at those points.

The function stack probably stores many things other than the arguments. However, for the sake of understanding recursion, knowing the value of the arguments at different recursive levels would suffice.

Comment: Ok, Thank You for the input